# Python matplotlib does not display data points - bug or something else?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I get an empty plot window (data points missing, correct axes etc.) when using the "," marker in matplotlib version 1.4.2 (it still works in 1.3.0, couldn't try anything in between) using the Qt4Agg backend.
In ipython --pylab:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.standard_normal(500)
b = np.random.standard_normal(500)
plot(a,b,',')
savefig("testplot.png")
savefig("testplot.pdf")
```

This produces an empty plot both on-screen and in the saved png file, but shows the expected randomly scattered points in the pdf file.

My system is Arch linux, kernel 3.17.6, matplotlib version 1.4.2, Python 3.4.2, IPython 2.3.1., numpy version 1.9.1, Qt4Agg backend.

Can anyone confirm this? Is this a real bug, or is my system somehow misconfigured? What other information should I provide?

---

Edit: I should mention that I posted this as a bug on the Arch bugtracker, where the response was that it was possibly an upstream issue. [Details here.](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/43392)

Comment: Either open a bug report with mpl right away, or, if you want to be of better help, first build mpl (1.4.2, and maybe master) from source and try to reproduce, possibly with multiple backends. If this happens with master and with multiple backends, then this likely is a real bug.

Comment: same happens for me on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Thanks. If it happens on Arch and Ubuntu, it's probably a real bug. I'll go write a bugreport then...

Comment: only way I can get it to write to the png and pdf is `matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend('cairo')`, I also have `cairocffi` installed